# Does Lean have a standard ASCII representation?

Tags: lean, unicode

From Lean 4 [tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/dependent_type_theory.html), I learned that

> In the Lean standard library, you often see Greek letters to denote
> types, and the Unicode symbol → as a more compact version of ->

and you can also type the arrow symbol → as either `\to` or `\r`.

The use of Unicode worries me a little bit just as when I first saw the different zeros and ones (in bold font etc.) in Isabelle. I was worried that I might miss the fine differences between some Unicode symbols and ASCII, and maybe elsewhere given the very large alphabet of Unicode and the fact that I haven't seen all the Unicode characters. But I was relieved to see that the Isabelle thm files are/can be stored in pure ASCII forms such as

`\<leftarrow>`, `\<one>`, etc.

My questions are:

*Does Lean have similar ASCII representations in Lean files? Or are Lean files inherently Unicode?*

*Are there canonical ASCII representations?  e.g. which of `->`, `\to` or `\r` is the standard way?*

Comment: I understand the urge to use ASCII (heck, I think libraries should store paper) – but could you explain what your worry is about? Is it about the human-computer interaction, i.e., that the human will be confused? Or that we won't be able to backport Lean to 1970 when we invent time travel? The HCI worry is real: the other day a colleague complained Agda standard library used Unicode whitespaces as operators (he was using a font with missing Unicode characters). If we invent time travel, Unicode won't be the main problem.

Comment: more interesting question might be to know the list of Unicode chars that Lean reserved for operators etc., e.g. $\lambda$

Comment: @GuyCoder: You're getting younger.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no standard ASCII representation that is equivalent to an arbitrary Lean 4 file using Unicode, and I'm not aware of such a thing for any other language. (Isabelle uses that encoding because it does *not* use Unicode and in fact adds many symbols and formatting not part of Unicode. Which makes looking at Isabelle files with any other tools, e.g. `git`, problematic).

The core term syntax accepts both ASCII and Unicode keywords:

```
src/Lean/Parser/Term.lean:@[builtinTermParser] def depArrow := leading_parser:25 bracketedBinder true >> unicodeSymbol " → " " -> " >> termParser
src/Lean/Parser/Term.lean:def «forall» := leading_parser:leadPrec unicodeSymbol "∀" "forall" >> many1 (ppSpace >> (simpleBinder <|> bracketedBinder)) >> ", " >> termParser
src/Lean/Parser/Term.lean:@[builtinTermParser] def «fun» := leading_parser:maxPrec ppAllowUngrouped >> unicodeSymbol "λ" "fun" >> (basicFun <|> matchAlts)
```

Many notations on top of this core, e.g. in [Notation.lean](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/master/src/Init/Notation.lean), however, do not. The Lean standard library always prefers the Unicode variant except for `fun` (because working with Lean should be `fun` (this is not an officially endorsed statement)).

Answer (score 7):

Answering specifically the concern:

> I might miss the fine differences between some Unicode symbols

it may be worth noting that on hovering over a character in a Lean aware editor (e.g. the Lean extension to VSCode) shows a tooltip containing the `\something` code one can type to produce that character. (I guess some unicode characters used in Lean don't have such a code; if you notice these it's probably worth adding them!)

This can be used to disambiguate similar characters.

Further, it would be reasonable to object during a pull request, or to make a pull request, if there are files which are using unreasonably similar unicode symbols unnecessarily.

Comment: (You might reasonably point a finger at me, for introducing the `⟶` arrow used in the category theory library as an alternative to the usual `→` function arrow built in to the language.)